# Possible to use TLS with Heroku for free?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku, https

Heroku wants me to pay them in order to run my site over TLS. However, using a free Let's Encrypt certificate, it looks like I should be able to run an HTTPS server and redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS. https://drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/
That article makes it sound like it's possible for Spring apps to use TLS. Will Heroku block this? Do I need to pay Heroku, or is this a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku gives you a free https://appname.herokuapp.com URL and free certificate management with Hobby dynos https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management